# Most efficient way to find a duplicate key in a list of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a list of objects I am iterating over. At some point I make an ajax call to add more objects to the list (could be many times).

Is there an efficient way to exclude any objects from being added to the list if one of the values matches an existing value?

For instance:

**An Existing List**

```
[
  {"value": "1", "id": "123"},
  {"value": "2", "id": "124"},
  {"value": "3", "id": "125"}
]
```

**Exclude the first object from being added since it has an id that is already in the list**

```
[
  {"value": "1", "id": "123"},
  {"value": "2", "id": "234"},
  {"value": "3", "id": "235"}
]
```

Comment: Can you store the values in a different structure? You could use `{ "123": "1" , ... } `

Comment: One way is transform the array into object (id-map); Another way would be to first sort by ID before insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `id` is unique, why not to use something like `map`.

- You can create and save a separate `var map = {};`
- Then every time new object comes in you do the following: `map['123'] = true;`

More like:

```
if (!map[new_id])
{
    map[new_id] = true;
    your_array.push({"value": "3", "id": "235"});
}
else
{
    // do what you want... maybe update the value
}
```

So in this way, you won't push any objects with existing `id`.

Comment: That looks perfect. The map would just contain a copy of the objects in my list?

Comment: the map will keep all your unique ids, then whenever you get new objects from Ajax call, you can easily check with you map whether it is duplicate. If not, then push it into your array.

Comment: Of course the complexity is O(n), not O(1), because the engine has to do the iteration internally.

Comment: I deleted that part not to confuse anyone. Of course there is some internal complexity going on. What I meant was, on OP's side it looks like O(1), since he/she does not have to use loops.

Answer (score 1):

The object's `_array` and `_hash` reference the same objects, and so the memory overhead is limited to references in the array and in the hash but not full copies of the objects.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbjWK/

```
function UniqueArray(array, key) {
    this._array = [];    
    this._hash = {};
    this._key = key;

    this.concat(array);
}

UniqueArray.prototype.concat = function(array) {
    var i, len;

    for (i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        this.push(array[i]);
    }
}

UniqueArray.prototype.push = function(obj) {
    if (!this._hash[obj[this._key]]) {
        this._hash[obj[this._key]] = obj;
        this._array.push(obj);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
// Testing testing
var first = [
  {"value": "1", "id": "123"},
  {"value": "2", "id": "124"},
  {"value": "3", "id": "125"}
];

var second = [
  {"value": "1", "id": "123"},
  {"value": "2", "id": "234"},
  {"value": "3", "id": "235"}
]

var ua = new UniqueArray(first, "id");
ua.concat(second);

console.log(ua._array);
```